# Type error with types recursive on their type argument

Tags: kotlin, generics

I got something like this :

```
interface Quantity<V : PValue<*>>
class Value<T : Value<T>> : Quantity<T>
```

The problem is, when I try to pass a `Value<*>` where a `Quantity<Value<*>>` is expected, the compiler either issues me a warning, or even an error, depending on something I didn't yet identify. I don't undertstand why this doesn't work, since a `Quantity`'s type argument has to be a `Value`, so every `Quantity` should pratically be a `Quantity<Value<*>>`, and since `Value`s implement `Quantity`, I don't understand why this won't work.

I tried to replace the `T : Value<T>` by a `T : Value<*>` in the `Value` class declaration, because I am aware that the problem might come from this recursion, but this apparently "violates the finite bound restriction"...

Last thought, maybe this has something to do with the in/out modifiers, but I can't make V `out` or `in` for `Quantity` because of methods that aren't present here for the purpose of simplicity.

Comment: What is the definition of `PValue`? Or it's just a typo and you meant `Value`?

Answer (score 0):

Generic types in Kotlin are [invariant](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#variance) (because they were initially invariant in Java), meaning that `MutableList<String>` is not a subtype of `MutableList<Any?>`.

To pass a `Value<*>` where a `Quantity<Value<*>>` is expected, you need to make type argument *covariant*, either on declaration-site:

```kotlin
interface Quantity<out V : Value<*>>
class Value<out T : Value<T>> : Quantity<T>

fun call(x: Quantity<Value<*>>) {}

fun f(value1: Value<*>) {
    call(value1)
}
```

or on usage-site:

```kotlin
interface Quantity<V : Value<*>>
class Value<T : Value<T>> : Quantity<T>


fun call(x: Quantity<out Value<*>>) {}

fun f(value1: Value<*>) {
    call(value1)
}
```

Comment: Works. Thanks !

Comment: "List<String> is not a subtype of List<Any?>" is not quite correct, because List is covariant in its type parameter by declaration: interface List<out T>. The MutableList interface however is indeed invariant.